# How to trigger intents on item selection from spinner

Tags: java, android, adt

I'm quite confused, I'd like to learn how I can trigger an intent from a spinner selection.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    //TextView myText= (TextView) view;
    //Toast.makeText(this, "You Selected "+myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Where the //textview and //toast lines are commented, I'd like to trigger an intent based on the spinner selection.

Sorry, and thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch in here in order to distinguish selected item, then start the appropriate activity. arg2 is the position of item in the spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

    Intent i = null;
    switch (arg2){
       case 0:
          i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, FooActivity.class);
          break;
       case 1: // etc 
          break;
    }

    startActivity(i);
```

}

Comment: Thank you. It works, but when MainActivity loads, case 0 is triggered immediately. Can this be stopped before user input?

Comment: Or is there an easy way to nullify case 0 so it does nothing? thanks

Comment: You can put a flag and check if it's first time to reload and check it in for case 0 only, or simply remove the case 0